# How to sort lines based on specific part of their value?

Tags: bash, shell

When I run the following command:

```
command list -r machine-a-.* | sort -nr
```

It gives me the following result:

```
machine-a-9
machine-a-8
machine-a-72
machine-a-71
machine-a-70
```

I wish to sort these lines based on the number at the end, in descending order.
( Clearly `sort -nr` doesn't work as expected. )

Comment: You just need to sort it on the delimiter `-`, should do `sort -t'-' -nr -k3 `

Comment: Also this question is much more applicable in [Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Inian I have just seen that you have suggested the same solution as me, only 10 minutes before me. Can you explain to me why did you write it here and not as an official answer?

Comment: @Iskustvo: I wasn't sure if OP was asking for the number alone or the whole line containing the number. Also this question is not quite appropriate in StackOverflow people would say. In general question seeking information on shell tools should be relevant in Unix.SE

Comment: @Inian I understand, it is a bit ambiguous... As for the Unix.SE, well I think that StackExchange made it a lot hard to know where to ask question in comparison to this ambiguity :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need the `-t` and `-k` options in the `sort`.

```
command list -r machine-a-.* | sort -t '-' -k 3 -nr
```

`-t` is the separator used to separate the fields.
By giving it the value of `'-'`, `sort` will see given text as:

```
Field 1  Field 2  Field 3    
machine    a        9
machine    a        8
machine    a        72
machine    a        71
machine    a        70
```

`-k` is specifying the field which will be used for comparison.
By giving it the value `3`, `sort` will sort the lines by comparing the values from the `Field 3`.
Namely, these **strings** will be compared:

```
9
8
72
71
70
```

`-n` makes `sort` treat the fields for comparison as numbers instead of strings.

`-r` makes `sort` to sort the lines in reverse order(descending order).

Therefore, by sorting the **numbers** from `Field 3` in reverse order, this will be the output:

```
machine-a-72
machine-a-71
machine-a-70
machine-a-9
machine-a-8
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of input to sort:

```
$ cat 1.txt
machine-a-9
machine-a-8
machine-a-72
machine-a-71
machine-a-70
```

Here is our short program:

```
$ cat 1.txt | ( IFS=-; while read A B C ; do  echo $C $A-$B-$C; done ) | sort -rn | cut -d' '  -f 2
```

Here is its output:

```
machine-a-72
machine-a-71
machine-a-70
machine-a-9
machine-a-8
```

Explanation:

```
$ cat 1.txt  \        (put contents of file into pipe input)
| (          \        (group some commands)
  IFS=-;              (set field separator to "-" for read command)
  while read A B C ;  (read fields in 3 variables A B and C every line)
     do  echo $C $A-$B-$C;    (create output with $C in the beggining)
  done 
  )          \         (end of group)
| sort -rn   \         (reverse number sorting)
| cut -d' '  -f 2      (cut-off first unneeded anymore field)
```